# Make two sets of buttons go side by side in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two sets (one with two buttons and one with only one button) of buttons side by side. However, one of my buttons is in a form, so I don't know how to do it.

This is the HTML code:

```
<form>
     //Some other things
    <div class="wrapper">
    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Login
    </button>
      </div>
  </form>

<div class="wrapper">

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToSignup()">
    New account
  </button>

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
    Forgot password
  </button>
</div>
```

The login button needs to be in the form, so I can't move it out.

This is the CSS for wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdKqk.png)

[This is how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elUpC.png)

EDIT:

Here is the full HTML code:

```
<ion-content padding>


  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-icon">
      <img src="{{logo}}">
    </div>
  </div>

    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.email.dirty"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.email.valid  && loginForm.controls.email.dirty">
        <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.password.valid && loginForm.controls.password.dirty"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="ios-key-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.password.valid  && loginForm.controls.password.dirty">
        <p>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</p>
      </ion-item>

      <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Login
    </button>

    </form>
          <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToSignup()">
    New account
  </button>

      <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
    Forgot password
  </button>

  <button ion-button block class="facebook-btn" (click)="facebookLogin()">
     <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" class="icons"> </ion-icon>
      Login with Facebook</button>

  <button ion-button block class="google-btn" (click)="googleLogin()">
     <ion-icon name="logo-google" class="icons"></ion-icon>
      Login with Google</button>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: you need to wrap all those in a div

Comment: @Hash: So the form also has to be included?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this layout. I've restructured your HTML, let me know if you have any questions...

```css
.wrapper,
.wrapper__options {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper form {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper form button {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper__options {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper__options button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form>
    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Login
    </button>
  </form>

  <div class="wrapper__options">
    <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToSignup()">
    New account
   </button>

    <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
    Forgot password
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, have tried your solution, but the buttons appear on the other things I have in the form (2 text fields). These buttons should appear below the text fields

Comment: @GeorgeW It's difficult to provide a solution for you without seeing the full HTML. Could you update your question please?

Comment: Yes sure, I am updating it now

Comment: Be careful using flexbox if you need to support IE. It's not supported in < IE 11 and it's only partially supported in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

The class wrapper should be attached to form tag.
You need to change your css and html accordingly.

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper button {
  display: block;
}

<form class="wrapper">

    <div >
    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Login
    </button>
      </div>
  </form>

<div class="wrapper">

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToSignup()">
    New account
  </button>

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
    Forgot password
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: block for your other buttons.Note type = button on your other two buttons so they don't submit the form  =button on your other two button Here's a working solution on pluncker https://plnkr.co/edit/xgksUqSwuMJR9IEQS1G7?p=preview

```
<style>
.block-buttons button {
  display: block;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<form>

    <div class="wrapper">

    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Login
    </button>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block-buttons">
      <button type=button class="breaker" ion-button block clear (click)="goToSignup()">
    New account
  </button>

  <button type=button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
    Forgot password
  </button>

  </div>
   </div>


  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap code with a div and display as inline-flex,

```
<div class="aa">
<!-- code-->
</div>
```

Css

```
.aa{
display: inline-flex;
}
```